# Ellipses in macOS UI

Tags: macos, ui

For macOS UI design, what does the ellipsis (tripple dot) puntuation mean?  For example, in the picture below, why does the button "Delete Service..." have it, but "Make Inactive" doesn't?

In an effort to figure it out myself, I found an [interesting article](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ellipses.html) describing what ellipses mean -- either an omission or a trailing of thought.  To me, that doesn't make sense.

[image: screenshot of Thunderbolt Bridge in Settings with the described (above) buttons]

Comment: It basically means there's another dialog to go through. Pressing "Delete Service" won't delete the service straight away, but take you to another dialog first.

Comment: This isn't anything particularly new. Although I have never used any Apple product in my life, Microsoft Windows has used ellipses like this for 30 years.

Comment: Your "interesting article" only describes one use of the ellipsis - indicating omitted words in a sentence or paragraph. Ellipses are also used to indicate an unfinished phrase or sentence. See https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/grammar-punctuation-and-conventions/punctuation-and-capitalisation/ellipses. It is the second meaning that leads to Apple's usage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you seem to be asking all sorts of questions about Apple UI design and aren't including a relevant practical problem you face. Keep in mind - developers of software should be asking questions on Stack Overflow or other places designed to learn the craft of software design. We focus on practical questions - so if you really can't understand how to operate the OS - that's legitimately on scope, but what are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [Apple’s Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/menus), the ellipses are there because more user input is needed to complete the action.

> **Append an ellipsis to a menu item’s label when people need to provide additional information before the action can complete.** The ellipsis character (…) signals that another view will open in which people can input information or make choices.

Specifically for [Buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/buttons):

> **Append a trailing ellipsis to the title when a push button opens another window, view, or app.** Throughout the system, an ellipsis in a control title signals that people can provide additional input. For example, the Edit buttons in the AutoFill pane of Safari Settings include ellipses because they open other views that let people modify autofill values.

Therefore, in this case, the button *Make Inactive* will simply perform the action while the buttons *Delete Service…* and *Details…* will bring up additional windows for user interaction.